# badges disappeared from profile

Tags: support, badges

I have two gold baďges: fanatic and copy editor, today I achieved 600 voting and suddenly I have again 2 gold badges only, the voting badge was cancelled .It is strange

Comment: It might take up to 24 hours for the system to process and give you your badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see all three on your profile:

[image: profile badges]

Sometimes new badges take a while to show up, but old badges should never disappear.  (Except for tag badges, if you drop below the minimum score or number of posts.)

Comment: Congrats kouty on the shiny gold badge!

Comment: @Double AA thanks so much.